# cast String to Image Id to modify in flex

Tags: apache-flex, string, image, casting

i'm trying to modify a image, which is casted from a String:

```
[Embed(source='map.swf', symbol='wZero')]
[Bindable]
private var wZero:Class;

[Embed(source='map.swf', symbol='wOne')]
[Bindable]
private var wOne:Class;

public function setInactiveElements () : void {
    trace ("setInactiveElements called");
    inactiveElements : Array = mapMan.getInactiveElements();
    for each ( var element : String in inactiveElements ) {
        trace ("inactiveElement: " + element );
        Image(element).alpha = 0.5;
                // also tried: 
                (element as Image).alpha =  0.5;
    }
}
```

In the inactiveElements Array are a bunch of ImageIds (way_0, way_1,..) and i'm trying to set the alpha-value of each Image.

```
<mx:Image source="{wZero}" id="way_0"/>
<mx:Image source="{wOne}" id="way_1"/>
```

with the trace i got the right String of ImageId but the cast to Image fails.

> TypeError: Error #1009: Der Zugriff
>   auf eine Eigenschaft oder eine Methode
>   eines null-Objektverweises ist nicht
>   möglich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
Image(this[element]).alpha = 0.5;
```

A `String` can never become an `Image`. The image is a property of of the `this` object keyed on the `String` `element`

---

If this solution doesn't work, please post more of your code.

Comment: Great!!

Thanks a'lot!

It Works!